# How Do I perform a multiple search in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program in visual basic. And I need to to search some values simultaneously. The database I have imported is an access database. What do I need to do in order to search multiple data inside my database and get multiple results. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what specifically you are trying to accomplish, but if I understood you correctly a simple query with multiple parameters will search for multiple data:

Example:

`SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourField IN ('data1','data2','data3')`

In the query above, you are searching `YourField` in table `YourTable` for 3 string values at the same time: `data1`, `data2` and `data3`. You will receive multiple records, assuming they fulfill your search criteria